# Loading specific application using SuperFetch in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, superfetch

SuperFetch feature loads most frequently used applications into RAM to make faster loading time for those apps. Is there any way to tell SuperFetch service to load specific apps into RAM in Windows 7? For example, I'd like to load a game into RAM using SuperFetch so that whenever I launch the game I'll get faster loading time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only control you can do of the SuperFetch feature is via the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters`, which contains `EnablePrefetcher` that may have the following values:

- 0 : To completely disable the SuperFetch feature
- 1 : To optimize only application startup
- 2 : To optimize only the computer startup process
- 3 : To optimize both application startup and the computer startup

This is the only control you have. Its default value is 3, and should be left like that.

The rest is automatic: If you use a certain application a lot, it will be prefetched when Windows sees fit according to how it analyzed your usage patterns. For example, it might prefetch some applications immediately after boot, and others only in the morning.

Comment: While you might be right, do you have any source for your claim? It would make sense if there was a way to specify a list of files or directories to prefetch along the automatically detected ones.